# how to filter meta tags from xss

Tags: php, html, xss

At my CMS I want to give site moderators ability to associate any meta information to a page. For meta keywords and description I have different fields but all other stuff are inserted like raw html, like this:

```
<meta name="Generator" content="Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)" />
<meta name="robots" content="nofollow" />
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/content/poisk-i-upravlenie-kontentom" />
```

Mainly only meta tags and link(rel=canonical) will be here.
And now I think I have to make sure there is no xss attack in this code.

HtmlPurifier or http://github.com/voku/anti-xss don't work with meta tags.
So what would you advise me?
To parse text with regexp for meta tags and then check every metatag found for any `style` or `on` attributes or `http-equiv="refresh"`(to deny malicious metatag)?

Comment: How are the meta tags inserted? Inputted as raw HTML or something else?

Comment: I think you should not have this input as full html. No input filter will be good enough against XSS, which is an output vulnerability. All variables need to be encoded upon writing them to the page, which you can't do if you receive full html segments.

Comment: **To RamenChef**: user inters html to a form -> I filter it and save to database -> when page is being rendered just echo $thisFilteredMetaTags.